# Passing the non-NODE_ENV variables from gulpfile to other js-files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Can I pass some variable **which is not** `NODE_ENV` from the `gulpfile.js` tо other `javascript` file?

**gulpfile.js**

```
// Not related with NODE_ENV!
let isDevelopment = true;
```

**somejsfile.js**

```
/*
I need to get "isDevelopment" from the gulpfile.js...

For the production build, where no NodeJS avaliable, this condition will be
always "false". Maybe it's possible to delete it by webpack.
*/ 

if (isDevelopment) {  
    printDebugInfromation();
}

// No neccessirity to print it in the production build
function printDebugInfromation() {
    console.log(/* ... */)
}
```

Why I don't use `NODE_ENV` is necessity to change it value from console.

Also, I always use `webpack` and config it inside `gulpfile.js`, so maybe some webpack plugins make it possible...

Answer (score 2):

if you don't care about collisions in global namespace

```
// gulpfile.js
global.isDevelopment = true;

// somejsfile.js
console.log(global.isDevelopment);
```

or you can create some configuration module

```
// my-evn.js module
const env = {};

module.exports = {
   set(key, value) {
      Object.assign(env, { [key]: value });
   },
   get(key) {
      return env[key];
   }
}
// or just like a global-like variable
module.exports = env;
```

then in gulpfile.js

```
const myEnv = require('./my-env.js');

myEnv.set('isDevelopment', true)
```

and in somejsfile.js

```
const myEnv = require('./my-env.js');

console.log(myEnv.get('isDevelopment'));
```

or something like this, getter with string keys isn't the best solution as for me, but the idea here to use some shared module with local storage.

Answer (score 1):

If to use `webpack`, `Define` plugin can do it:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        IS_DEVELOPMENT: isDevelopment
    })
]
```